# Keycloak admin client Java api

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

I am trying to use keycloak-admin-client module in one of our custom User storage SPI implementations

But, while trying to start the server in dev mode, I am receiving the following error.

```
ERROR: Failed to run 'build' command.
Error details:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doReaugment(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:48)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:32)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.command.Build.run(Build.java:75)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1939)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2358)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2352)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2314)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2179)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2316)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2078)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.Picocli.runReAugmentation(Picocli.java:184)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.Picocli.runReAugmentationIfNeeded(Picocli.java:121)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.Picocli.parseAndRun(Picocli.java:89)
    at org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.KeycloakMain.main(KeycloakMain.java:88)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:61)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigSource: org.jboss.resteasy.microprofile.config.ServletConfigSource not a subtype
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:593)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1244)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder.discoverSources(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:97)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig$ConfigSources.buildSources(SmallRyeConfig.java:586)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig$ConfigSources.<init>(SmallRyeConfig.java:542)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.<init>(SmallRyeConfig.java:68)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder.build(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:449)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigFactory$Default.getConfigFor(SmallRyeConfigFactory.java:59)
    at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigProviderResolver.getConfig(SmallRyeConfigProviderResolver.java:76)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:181)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:331)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createProductionApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:175)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.mutability.ReaugmentTask.main(ReaugmentTask.java:69)
    ... 26 more
```

I have managed to start the server by doing the below but not able to use the keycloak admin client as it's missing the required dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>*</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Any insight/suggestions on why this is happening would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the keycloak admin client quarkus extension instead (or its reactive counterpart if you use reactive)

### Standard

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-keycloak-admin-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

### Reactive

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-keycloak-admin-client-reactive -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-keycloak-admin-client-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If replacing dependency doesn't solve your problem, please add reproducer and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I tried with `quarkus-keycloak-admin-client`, I got `Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigFactory: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.QuarkusConfigFactory not a subtype`. Here is the reproducer

https://github.com/mparthasarathi/kc-storage-spi